# Django printing my queryset

Tags: python, html, django, django-queryset

I've just started with Django and I am trying to print my queryset object. My template code is given below:

```
{% for record in qset  %}
        {{record.first}}, {{record.second}}
{%endfor%}
```

Also, my views file contains:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from updatedb.models import Data
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

def index(request):
        return render(request, 'updatedb/data.html')

def submit(request):
        first = request.POST["first"]
        second = request.POST["second"]
        d = Data()
        d.first = first
        d.second = second
        d.save()

        if request.POST.get("submit"):
                qset = Data.objects.all()
                print qset[2].first
                print qset[2].second
                return render(request, 'updatedb/results.html', {'queryset':qset}
```

On running the server and submitting my data I am getting a blank web page. Why is that so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `qset` in your template to `queryset` because the name `qset` is not passed to your template.

```
        {{record.first}}, {{record.second}}
{% endfor %}
```

by the way, your parentheses need to be closed with a `)` on the last line.

Comment: Your variable name in your template should be the same with the one that is passed in the render() function in your views.py. In the code you posted, you are using `{'queryset':qset}` to pass parameters to template, that's why you need to use `queryset` in your template. And on your last line, the render function is `render(`, without a closing `)`, but it's probably a copy&paste error,that's what I mean in the 'btw' above.